# Computer Vision as an Independent site on Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

Having a look at different [sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) of Stack Exchage, it feels like **Computer Vision** page is really missing!

There obviously exists almost relevant pages, such as [AI](https://ai.stackexchange.com/), [Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/), [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/), [Computer Graphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/) and [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) in which people can ask questions.

Why does not Stack Exchange make one specific page for researchers or anyone with interests in the area of Computer Vision?

Is there any particular reason or is it more of multidisciplinary subjects according to the founder of Stack Exchange?

Comment: Please, see [https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344835/287113](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344835/287113) meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does not Stack Exchange make one specific page for researchers or anyone with interests in the area of Computer Vision?

Apparently, there was a proposal for a computer vision SE site, but [the proposal was deleted](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2799/82135) because of low activity. In general, if there aren't enough users interested in the topic and enough activity, the site will not be created.

Computer vision is clearly an AI topic, so, in general, any theoretical CV question is on-topic here. See [all our CV questions](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision).

Signal Processing SE is also an appropriate site to ask CV questions. In fact, in the past, I've asked some questions there. [Stats SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags) may also be an appropriate site to ask your question.

See also [Stack Exchange site to ask questions about computer vision?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2794/82135).

Comment: So there’s no possible way to revive that proposal anymore? Maybe there’ll be more activities

Comment: @FäridAlijani Yes, there's the possibility to create a new proposal. [Here's the site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) where you can possibly create it.